# Heroku and url forwarding issues without www

Tags: url, heroku

I have a working heroku app and have changed the url forwarding to my namecheap host. The full version of www.yadayada.com works perfectly. The problem is if I do yadayada.com it says

```
heroku | No such app
There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.
```

In namecheap I have the @ set to the Heroku url and the record type as cname alias. The same applies for the www. version.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku recommends you forward your apex domain (yadayada.com) to a subdomain (like www) and then CNAME that subdomain to your Heroku app. This allows Heroku to maintain high availability for you, otherwise your apex points to an IP, which can change.

If you insist on the apex domain, see Heroku's DevCenter guides:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains

Finally, I think this could be solved by simply adding yadada.com to your domains with this:

```
$ heroku domains:add yadada.com -a yadayada
```